# javascript is not active

Tags: javascript, html, css

Making my first calculator on javascript. My javascript code is not working,but javascript file is linked by . When it was all in html file it worked but not now. Seems everything good.What a problem? Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<html>
    <head>
    <script src="javascript/calc.js"></script>
    <link href="css/calc.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <TITLE>Calculator</TITLE>
    <style>
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
        <div id="calc-container">
        <form name="calculator">
        <input type="text" onkeyup="return proverka(this);" autofocus maxlength="10" placeholder="Введіть число" name="answer" />
        <br />

        <input type="button" value=" 1 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '1'" />
        <input type="button" value=" 2 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '2'" />
        <input type="button" value=" 3 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '3'" />
        <input type="button" value=" + " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '+'" />
        <br />

        <input type="button" value=" 4 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '4'" />
        <input type="button" value=" 5 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '5'" />
        <input type="button" value=" 6 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '6'" />
        <input type="button" value=" - " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '-'" />
        <br />

        <input type="button" value=" 7 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '7'" />
        <input type="button" value=" 8 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '8'" />
        <input type="button" value=" 9 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '9'" />
        <input type="button" value=" &#215; " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '*'" />
        <br />

        <input type="button" value=" C " onclick="calculator.answer.value = ''" />
        <input type="button" value=" 0 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '0'" />
        <input type="button" value=" = " onclick="calculator.answer.value = eval(calculator.answer.value)" />
        <input type="button" value=" &#247; " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '/'" />
        <br />

        <input type="button" value=" exp " onclick="calculator.answer.value = Math.exp(calculator.answer.value);" />
        <input type="button" value=" ln "  onclick="calculator.answer.value = Math.log(calculator.answer.value);" /> 
        <input type="button" value=" &#8730; " onclick="sqrt(calculator.answer.value)" />
        <input type="button" value=" x&#178; " onclick="sqr(calculator.answer.value)" />
        <br />

        <input type="button" value=" cos " onclick="calculator.answer.value = Math.cos(calculator.answer.value);" /> 
        <input type="button" value=" sin " onclick="calculator.answer.value = Math.sin(calculator.answer.value);" />
        <input type="button" value=" tan " onclick="calculator.answer.value = Math.tan(calculator.answer.value);" />
        <input type="button" value=" &larr; " onclick="backspace(calculator.answer.value);"; />
        <br />

        <p align=right>&#8226;Sergiy Starshoy &#169;</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>






<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function proverka(input)
 { 
    var value = input.value; 
    var rep = /[-;":'а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-ZA\\=`ё/\*++!@#$%\^&_№?><]/;
    var rep2 = /а|б|в|г|д|е|ё|ж|і|з|и|ё|к|л|м|н|о|п|р|с|т|у|ф|х|ц|ч|ш|щ|ъ|ы|ь|э|ю|я/gi;

        if (rep.test(value))
        { 
        value = value.replace(rep, ''); 
        input.value = value; 

            if (rep2.test(value))
            { 
                value = value.replace(rep2, ''); 
                input.value = value; 
            }
        } 

 }

function backspace(value)
{
calculator.answer.value = calculator.answer.value.substring(0, calculator.answer.value.length - 1)
return input.value;
}

function sqrt(value)
{
calculator.answer.value = Math.sqrt(value);
}

function sqr(value) {
calculator.answer.value = (calculator.answer.value)*(calculator.answer.value);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the HTML from the script file, leave only the javascript code.

Comment: "When it was all in html file it worked but not now" where is it now?

Answer (score 3):

Your JavaScript file doesn't work because you added plain HTML inside the file. You need to remove the HTML tags surrounding the actual JavaScript code.

Basically, the .js file needs all the code that's between the script tags and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

if it works when you have your javascript inside the html but not in external file then probably you have the path to the js file wrong. if your project folder has 2 folders inside (one with html files and 1 with Js files) then on your path  
with the ../ you go up one level on your folder and then go inside your javascript folder to find the file

Answer (score -1):

Why do you redefine a whole HTML code?
Put your Javascript code into a `<script></script>` tag before closing the `<body>` tag.

Exemple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="..."></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ....

        <script>
             // Here some JS code
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```